# Determine group of unreadable unix/linux directory

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, directory, file-permissions

```
dcoles1@shovel:/ $ cd /DriveXT
dcoles1@shovel:/DriveXT $ ls
. unreadable
dcoles1@shovel:/DriveXT $ cd /DriveXT/MML/       
dcoles1@shovel:/DriveXT/MML $ ls
. unreadable
dcoles1@shovel:/DriveXT/MML $ cd /DriveXT/MML/LP2010/
bash: cd: /DriveXT/MML/LP2010/: Permission denied
```

So I know these folders exist... but how do I figure out the permissions of these folders? It won't let me do a "ls -l"... Can I find out what group owns "/DriveXT/MML/LP2010/"? and how can I get the "drwxr-x--x" string?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ls -ld /DriveXT will tell you the permissions on /DriveXT. You can't get the permissions on the lower ones, they are probably '--x' for you for MMT, and '---' for you for LP2010.
If you want to find out the permissions on the lower directories, you'll have to be root, or user with 'r' permission on those directories.